# Internet Explorer Selenium protractor e2e tests

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I would like to add to our CI build process some e2e tests. I have already added them against chrome + firefox (as the simplest ones). But I really want to do it for several IE versions. How is it possible to inject it in build process on linux/mac?

I found such article:
http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/

But looks like it is not 100% what I need. Could some one provide a simple configuration sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a [selenium server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), either your own, or at [`browserstack`](http://www.browserstack.com)/[`SauceLabs`](https://saucelabs.com/). If you are planning to do it on your own, in short, you would need to setup a *selenium grid* and register nodes, one of the nodes should be a windows machine where you would run tests against IE.

Personally, I've been successfully running protractor e2e tests on multiple browsers including different `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `IE` versions on browserstack. Here's the configuration I use (it also includes [`jasmine junit reporter`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters), needed this for the CI):

```
'use strict';

var browserstackUser = 'user';
var browserstackKey = 'key';

exports.config = {
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'browserstack.user': browserstackUser,
            'browserstack.key': browserstackKey,
            'browserstack.local': 'true',
            'browserstack.debug': 'true',

            'browserName': 'Chrome',
            'os': 'Windows',
            'os_version': '8',
            'resolution': '1024x768',

            specs: [
                '*.spec.js'
            ],
            exclude: [
                'footer.disabledCookies.spec.js'
            ]
        },

        {
            'browserstack.user': browserstackUser,
            'browserstack.key': browserstackKey,
            'browserstack.local': 'true',
            'browserstack.debug': 'true',

            'browser': 'Internet Explorer',
            'browser_version': '8.0',
            'os': 'Windows',
            'os_version': '7',
            'resolution': '1024x768',

            specs: [
                '*.spec.js'
            ]
        },

        {
            'browserstack.user': browserstackUser,
            'browserstack.key': browserstackKey,
            'browserstack.local': 'true',
            'browserstack.debug': 'true',

            'browserName': 'Internet Explorer',
            'browser_version': '9.0',
            'os': 'Windows',
            'os_version': '7',
            'resolution': '1024x768',

            specs: [
                '*.spec.js'
            ],
            exclude: [
                'footer.disabledCookies.spec.js'
            ]
        }
    ],

    // Browserstack's selenium server address
    seleniumAddress: 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

    framework: 'jasmine',

    allScriptsTimeout: 300000,

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9001',

    onPrepare: function () {
        require('jasmine-reporters');
        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
        capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
            var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
            var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
            var prePendStr = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new
                jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter("test-results", true, true, prePendStr));
        });
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 3600000
    }
};
```

Comment: niceeee, I really have not thought about browserstack... We have already had an account here actually, but for some manual testing purposes, it could really work. I hope base automate subscription will be enough for 5 browser versions... it says 2 parallel tests

Comment: @user2174981 yeah, I think we are using the cheapest plan there with 2 parallel tests, for us it's enough but we are having automated tests running there only for a single internal project, we'll though use bs more extensively - will see if it would be enough. Glad it helped, happy testing.